# Facebook feed showing up with network error in IE10

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook & twitter feed . However the facebook feed does not display in IE10

```
<div class="right-col">
  <div class="latest-posts"> 

    <span class="heading icon-arrow-right-open">Latest Posts</span>

    <div class="tabs">
        <a href="#"><span class="tab icon-arrow-down-triangle" data-name="twitter">Twitter</span></a> 
        <a href="#"><span class="tab icon-arrow-down-triangle active" data-name="facebook">Facebook</span></a> 
    </div>


    <div class="panel facebook-panel show">

      <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcarsguide.australia&width=300&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&stream=true&header=false&height=300" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:314px; height:300px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>


    <div class="panel twitter-panel" style="overflow:hidden"> <a class="twitter-timeline" height="342" href="https://twitter.com/Carsguide" data-widget-id="349347183973257216">Tweets by @Carsguide</a> 
      <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script> 
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Link is [here](http://www.carsguide.com.au/)

Comment: So far, all I found is that the iframe probably works on IE10 alone. HOwever, something else in the site must be blocking it from displaying on IE10

Comment: Actually found the problem later on. It was our own company proxy that was blocking it. Not an issue anymore